# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error and I am not able to fix it

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.print_print.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.keshav.fbasetest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }


    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-notice.md'
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.1'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried looking at prior solutions and implementing them, but they didn't work. I also tried adding android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false to my gradle.properties but the code was still giving this error. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Try removing one of the "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" from your build.gradle. It looks like you have mentioned it two times.

Comment: Problem still persists

Comment: Firebase migrated to AndroidX in the latest releases. It means that you are using both, support libraries and androidx libraries. You have to migrate to androidx and remove the support libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what Gabriele said, migrating to androidx fixed the problems